# Using a function to free a linked list with double pointer

Tags: c, function, linked-list, free, double-pointer

I am having a tough time deleting all members in a linked in a single function. If I break it up like you see below, it works fine, but this seems wildly inefficient and want to figure out the correct way to do this. in order to free all nodes I need to have function to first free all nodes other then the head, then have a function free the head link. this seems like it would be easy to do but I am having trouble.

Thanks for the help!

```
int main() {

    struct node *head = NULL;
    createList(&head);

    //do stuff with list

    freeListMembers(head);
    freeListHead(&head);

    return 0;
}

int createList(struct node **head) {
    //create list
    return 0;
}

void freeListMembers(struct node *head){
    while(head->next != NULL){
        head->next = NULL;
        free(head->next);  
    }
    return;  
}

void freeListHead(struct node **head) {
    *head = NULL;
    free(*head); 
    return;
}
```

here is the code that I want to work but does not. the issue I am seeing is a an error for "*head->next;" where it sais "expression must have pointer to struct or union type"

```
int main() {

    struct node *head = NULL;
    createList(&head);

    //do stuff with list

    freeAllListMembers(&head);

    return 0;
}

int createList(struct node **head) {
    //create list
    return 0;
}

void freeAllListMembers(struct node **head){ 
    while (head != NULL) {
        struct node *temp = *head->next;
        free(*head);
        *head = temp ;
    }
   return;  
}
```

Comment: You *do* have a function that frees the head and all the members.  It's named `main()`.  Your question would be clearer, and would provide more traction for answers, if you present something you tried, and that therefore has the form you want, but that isn't working for you.

Comment: @JohnBollinger THanks! I added the code I want to work above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code :

```
void freeListMembers(struct node *head){
    while(head->next != NULL){
        head->next = NULL;
        free(head->next);  
    }
    return;  
}
```

This is freeing NULL, not your node*.

Freeing the list is as simple as using a temporary pointer to the next node.

```
while (head) {
    node* next = head->next;
    free(head);
    head = next;
}
```

From your edit :

```
void freeAllListMembers(struct node **head){ 
    while (head != NULL) {
        struct node *temp = *head->next;
        free(*head);
        *head = temp ;
    }
   return;  
}
```

There are a couple errors with this. It should be `while (*head != NULL)` and `(*head)->next`. The first is a logic error, because head will always be non-NULL, and the second is a syntax error, because you need to dereference the head pointer before accessing the next pointer.

Comment: Thanks @MarcD, I originally tried your suggestions, but this does not work, I added my code to my above thread with a little more info

Comment: I edited my answer to show you what was wrong with the code you tried.

Comment: this worked! thanks, the (head != NULL) was just a typo, but the (*head)->next was the part I was missing, why do you need the parathenses? what exactly is this doing? I was also thinking about setting *head = NULL; before free(*head);. I read that it is a best practice to set the pointer to null before freeing it, would this be correct for my situation as well?

Comment: Don't set the pointer to NULL before you free it, but after it, otherwise you're calling free on NULL, which is pointless. (`*head`) derefences the head pointer (which is a `node**`) which gives you a `node*`, which you can then access `->next` with. Google operator precedence to find out why. The member access (->) takes precedence over the dereference (*).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the insight!

Answer (score 0):

This will work. You just set next of head to null and freed head. Now we can not move to second element.So we wont be able to free the nodes.Also check base condition. I hope it helps

```
void freeListmembers(node *head){
node *temp=head;
if(head==NULL)//Base condition
return;
while(head->next!=NULL){
temp=head;//Moved temp to head. we will move head to next and free the previous node
head=head->next;
free(temp);
}
free(head);
return;
```

}

Comment: This is not a very clear or concise way to free the list. It works, but in a very roundabout way.

Comment: I agree. But I tried modifying as per thinking of the person who asked the question. So that he may know what he was doing.